# Wordpress - get_post_mime_type

Tags: wordpress, mime-types

I'm showing a list of files on a page with there mime type.

```
    $type = get_post_mime_type( $document['document'] );
```

For a pdf it outputs 'application/pdf'

Is it possible to remove the application and just show pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a simple `explode()` operation on the string:

```
$type = explode( '/', get_post_mime_type( $document['document'] ) );
echo $type[1];
```

Or write a custom function for more fine-grained control (based on Codex [example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_mime_type#Return_an_icon_image_path_according_to_the_MIME_type_of_the_given_post)):

```
function so28344776_get_mime_for_attachment( $post_id )
{
    $type = get_post_mime_type( $post_id );

    if( ! $type )
        return 'N/A';

    switch( $type )
    {
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/png':
        case 'image/gif':
            return "image";

        case 'video/mpeg':
        case 'video/mp4': 
        case 'video/quicktime':
            return "video";

        case 'text/csv':
        case 'text/plain': 
        case 'text/xml':
            return "text";

        case 'application/pdf':
            return "pdf";

        default:
            return "file";
    }
}

// usage
echo  so28344776_get_mime_for_attachment( $document['document'] );
```